# "What do you mean BY (something)?" - Is "BY" correct here?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

Usually, **BY** means near, beside, who made what, who did what, etc. But in this question,

> ***What do you mean BY (something)***?,

I can't figure out what it means here. Can we use other preposition here instead of "**BY**"?

Comment: "By" can mean *to the measure of*, as by a long shot, by a mile, by an hour. Here, more like *per*, *produced from*, *as a result of*.

Comment: A paraphrase would be 'What do you mean _when you say/write/..._ (something)?'

Comment: _By_ is the preposition required by _mean_ to identify the symbol whose "meaning" (i.e, symbolic content) is at issue. It's just a preposition; it doesn't have any meaning, so don't worry about what it means. It comes with the verb, like _at_ comes with _look_ and _to_ comes with _listen_.

Comment: Change the order to see if you like it: *By saying that, what do you mean?*

Answer (score 1):

Under meaning 2., *indicating the means of achieving something*, [OxfordL](https://www.google.com/search?q=by%20meaning&sxsrf=ALiCzsZpIdutef6K4jujl89wGK5EWkGMgA%3A1665147651399&ei=AyNAY7z7F_Gy8gL_oILwBQ&ved=0ahUKEwj8iIqyls76AhVxmVwKHX-QAF4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=by%20meaning&gs_lcp=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&sclient=gws-wiz) provides this definition:

> *indicating a term* to which an interpretation is to be assigned.
>
> - What is meant ***by*** ‘fair’?

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/by) puts it slightly differently:

> If you say what someone *means **by** a particular word or expression*, you are saying *what they intend the word or expression to refer to*.
>
> - Stella knew what he meant by 'start again'.

To paraphrase your question, you could say:

> What do you mean *BY* (***when you say/ use the term***) "X"?

Quoting *McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs*, [FreeDict](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/mean+by) lists *mean by* as an idiom:

> ***mean by something***
> to intend a certain meaning by words or deeds.